# puppet SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed

Tags: puppet

my puppet agent can't can't connect to the server which is running on the same machine. I am attempting to setup a puppet client server on raspbian linux using puppet version 5.5.0

First I tried deleting and regenerating all of the certs using using this guide https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html After interpreting that guide several different ways I get the same error. So I tried setting up the client and server on different machines and there was no change. 
I tried adding --waitforcert=60 so that the client would obtain the signed cert.
I tried uninstalling the client and server and deleting any files associated with puppet and reinstalling everything

Here is the error message I receive when running `puppet agent -t` :

```
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate rejected): [ok for /CN=raspberrypi]
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate rejected): [ok for /CN=raspberrypi]
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate rejected): [ok for /CN=raspberrypi]
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate rejected): [ok for /CN=raspberrypi]
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///plugins: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate rejected): [ok for /CN=raspberrypi]
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate rejected): [ok for /CN=raspberrypi]
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate rejected): [ok for /CN=raspberrypi]
```

Comment: I had to do this multiple times, and in some cases was an issue with me not following properly the docs, in other, because of to much memory consumption, PuppetDB service was brought down and I had to increase the memory and `jRuby`s for it.

Comment: There are related answers on Server Fault and elsewhere. How about https://serverfault.com/questions/655090/new-server-unable-to-fetch-configuration-from-puppetmaster-due-to-some-ssl-error, or https://ask.puppet.com/question/28644/what-is-happening-with-puppet-cert-here/?